# How do I center aligned vertically the text with my image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to vertically centered align the text with my image. Currently, the text looks like it's aligned at the bottom of the image.

Here's my jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/huskydawgs/L5Le0w37/7/

Here's my HTML:

```
    <div class="column-resources-box">
    <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple"><img alt="Apples" height="50" src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/acq/ezj/acqezjKcM.jpeg" width="50" /></a>

<h4 class="title-bar">Apple<br>
    Center</h4>

<ul>
    <li>Gala</li>
    <li>Pink Lady</li>
    <li>Fuji</li>
</ul>
</div>

Here's my CSS:

        .column-resources-box {
        width: 200px;
        float: left;
        margin: 15px;
    }

        .column-resources-box img {
    margin:0 2%;
    float:left;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
}
        }

h4.title-bar {
    color: #2251a4;
    background: none;
    font-family: 'Arial', inherit;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: typo in your `css` (remove extra `}`) and add some `padding` to the `h4` like: `padding: 12px 0` ... see basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/L5Le0w37/14/

Comment: did [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29528520/3624981) helped you solve your problem @user3075987 ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this out.
I wrapped the two items you want centered in the div, and then centered the image.

```css
.wrap {
    display:inline
}
.apple_image {
    vertical-align:middle
}    

.column-resources-box {
        width: 200px;
        float: left;
        margin: 15px;
    }

        .column-resources-box img {
    margin:0 2%;
    float:left;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
}
        }

h4.title-bar {
    color: #2251a4;
    background: none;
    font-family: 'Arial', inherit;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="column-resources-box">
    <div class="wrap">
        <a class="apple_image" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple">
            <img alt="Apples" height="50" src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/acq/ezj/acqezjKcM.jpeg" width="50" />
        </a>

        <h4 class="title-bar">AppleCenter</h4>
    </div>
<ul>
 <li>Gala</li>
 <li>Pink Lady</li>
 <li>Fuji</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a syntax error in your CSS. Here's your CSS, excerpted from the top:

```
        .column-resources-box {
        width: 200px;
        float: left;
        margin: 15px;
    }

        .column-resources-box img {
    margin:0 2%;
    float:left;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
}
        }
```

Notice the extraneous close brace. That seems to be preventing the browser from getting to the remaining CSS.

Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/L5Le0w37/13/

You can move it down a little to center it with `position:relative; top:7px;`:

Centered: http://jsfiddle.net/L5Le0w37/16/

Answer (score 0):

You could use absolute positioning to put things exactly where you want them.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t8rL871j/

```css
    .column-resources-box {
        width: 200px;
        float: left;
        margin: 15px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .column-resources-box img {
        margin:0 2%;
        height:50px;
        width:50px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    h4.title-bar {
        color: #2251a4;
        background: none;
        font-family:'Arial', inherit;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-transform: none;
        line-height: normal;
        margin: 0 0 0 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: left;
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 60px;
    }

    .column-resources-box ul {
        margin:60px 2%;
        height:50px;
        width:70px;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
<div class="column-resources-box"> <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple"><img alt="Apples" height="50" src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/acq/ezj/acqezjKcM.jpeg" width="50" /></a>

    
<h4 class="title-bar">Apple<br>
    Center</h4>

    <ul>
        <li>Gala</li>
        <li>Pink Lady</li>
        <li>Fuji</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your code a bit but here's another possible way using top padding..

```
vertical-align: top;
padding: 4px 0px 0px 0px; /* adjust top padding */
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/mj5yzsr7/3/

You can adjust the spacing between **Apple** and **Center** with `h4.title-bar { line-height: 25px; }` then adjust the top padding to compensate.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your text and image inside of a `div` and style it like this:

HTML

```
<div class="appleWrapper">
    <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple"><img alt="Apples" height="50" src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/acq/ezj/acqezjKcM.jpeg" width="50" /></a>
    <h4 class="title-bar">Apple<br>Center</h4>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.appleWrapper {
    height: 50px;
}
.title-bar {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

**Check out the [online example here](http://jsfiddle.net/rg9mj8d7/)**